# Unable to use @walletconnect/sign-client with angular/ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, webpack, wallet-connect

Trying to include @walletconnect/sign-client into my Ionic v5 project. Keep getting the following error. Not sure why. Do I need to install any specific webpack loader?

```js
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/@walletconnect/sign-client/dist/index.es.js 1:7237
[ng] Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:7237)
[ng] You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently, no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders




Dependencies:

 "@walletconnect/jsonrpc-types": "^1.0.1",
 "@walletconnect/sign-client": "^2.1.0",
 "@walletconnect/types": "^2.1.0",



Angular CLI: 9.1.15
Node: 14.19.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 9.1.13
... common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router, service-worker
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.803.29
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.901.15
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.901.15
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.901.15
@angular-devkit/core              9.1.15
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.1.15
@angular/cli                      9.1.15
@angular/fire                     6.1.5
@ngtools/webpack                  9.1.15
@schematics/angular               9.1.15
@schematics/update                0.901.15
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.8.3
webpack                           4.42.0
```